# Circular Import Solution

Tags: python, inheritance, python-import

How can I arrive at this setup in python:

```
class Garage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.car_list = []

    def add_car(self, car: Car):
        self.car_list.append(car)


class Car:
    def __init__(self, garage: Garage):
        self.garage = garage
        self.garage.add_car(self)

    def print_garage(self):
        print(f"This car's garage is {self.garage}")
```

Garage needs to know about Car in order to ensure that only Cars are added to its 'car_list'.
Car needs to know about Garage in order to ensure that it is added to a valid Garage, and to access the Garage's properties/methods.

I need to ensure that the Garage holds Cars and that each Car can access details of its Garage.

I've tried moving Car and Garage into separate files (car.py and garage.py), and in a sandbox.py script I have:

```
import car
import garage

new_garage = garage.Garage()

new_car = car.Car(
    garage=new_garage
)
```

This gives this error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
partially initialized module 'car' has no attribute 'Car' (most likely due to a circular import)
```